# Difference between google managed certificates and lets encrypt

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, lets-encrypt, google-cloud-load-balancer

I am trying to secure my domain which is hosted in gcp.I am thinking of using a google managed certificate but it will be costly since i will have to use a load balancer as to let's encrypt which is inside my vm instance. Is there a significant difference between them? Any thoughts would be appreciated

I am still on the building phase.

Comment: For your endusers (ie the ones that are connecting to your service) there is no noteable difference. Both certificate authorities are trusted per default in all reasonably modern environments. For you as service provider, the difference is, that you yourself are responsible, that the certificate is renewed in time (and your service starts using new certificate). LE certificates are valid for 90 days only, so you probably will need some automation of this process. With google managed certificates, google will take care of this, once you set up your certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cloud loadbalancer would be the better option as it is much more secured and efficient if you think about the overall value. Here is a good read about cloud load balancing since you are on the building phase. [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your requirement! You can, indeed, deploy your own certificate on your VM to avoid the use of a load balancer.

But the value added of a load balancer is not only managing the certificate. Especially, think about your production. Will you have only one VM? Or do you want high availability and have a pool of VM?

If you have a pool of VM, you will need a load balancer to dispatch the traffic across them.

Same idea if you need a WAF (Cloud Armor), rate limiting and others. Load balancer will, soon or later, come in the picture.